# How do I access security role in cloudkit

Tags: ios8, cloudkit

I am building an app with Role based Security.  I have built my Record Types (Projects, Accounts, HistoryLog, Financial, Customer, etc) in Cloudkit Dashboard, and I have created Security Roles as well.  I have roles named: Executive and DeptManager.  I have assigned to the Record Types the appropriate access by Role.  I have also assigned to the user in the special Record Type "Users" the role of either Executive or DeptManager.

I have successfully accessed and manipulated data in the Record Types.  Now I am implementing Role based viewing in the App.  So on the first view there is a log in "like" feature, so after i discover the user, I want to display the Roles of that user in a PickerView for them to select.  Once they select a role I will them take them to the appropriate view.  For example I may have the role of both DeptManager and Executive.  If today I select DeptManager, I will be taken to a view that allows me to enters Production Metrics.  If another day I select Executive, I will see performance metrics for all the departments that report to me.

Here is an image from CloudKit Dashboard showing the info I'm trying to retrieve.  Thanks in advance for any advice.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Currently it is not possible to get the roles a user is in. At the moment the information that is returned from the discoverUserInfoWithUserRecordID is very limited. I also hope it will be extended soon. Currently you only get a userRecordID, first name and last name. If you do want such functionality, then the only solution is creating a shadow registration which you could query. You then would have a challenge keeping these 2 in sync. That has to be done manually.

Comment: Starting from iOS 9 you won't even get a first and last name. You have to implement identification logic yourself.

Comment: You still get first and last name in iOS 9. But it's through the property that gives a CNContact.