# Cloudkit Security Roles

Tags: ios, security, cloudkit

The only use I can see for Security Rolls in CloudKit is granting another team member access to the cloudkit Dashboard in order to modify the tables in the dashboard? Is this correct, or am I missing something?

Currently I am the only one who can login to the dashboard and I can't add another team Member. I think this is because I am registered as a single developer with Apple? I was hoping to use this to set up some type of security on the public database but it seems that I can't do that with security roles.

I am trying to set up three different types of users for the public database:

I will have 3 apps running in this same container.

1.) Admin - Separate App

2.) Consumer - Separate App

3.) Contractor - Separate App

I found this thread:

[How do I access security role in cloudkit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25570212/how-do-i-access-security-role-in-cloudkit)

It appears that I have to add the security in each app to access only the data allowed for that type of user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have setup multiple apps sharing the same container, you need to not only configure this in Xcode itself, but also in the code you write.

```
let container = CKContainer(identifier: "iCloud.yourDB")
let publicDB = container.publicCloudDatabase
```

Access is granted on a iCloud user basis, not an app basis. So if your going to have all three apps running on devices using the same iCloud ID, than they will all have access to the same public & private databases, with the default permissions.

You would need "code" the ability to "create" & "write-to" your database in the admin app. Presumably "write-to" the database in the contractor app and "read-from" the database in your consumer app; an example scenario.

However if the plan is for multiple iCloud users to use different apps sharing the same container, than your options are more limited. The private database is just that, private. So different iCloud users cannot share the same private database, you can not change the permissions period, they can only share the public database.

In the public database default permissions will grant everybody read access, only allow authenticate [logged into iCloud account] users the ability to create new records and link said created records with the users that created them.

Put another way if an authenticated User [A] creates a record in the public database, user [B] can read it, but has no write access to update it; you would/could change access to give them the right to do so if you that was a requirement, a change you would make on the dashboard.

But beware, the quota on the public database are not linked to the iCloud accounts as I understand it, they are linked to the app. So if you create an app that dumps large amounts of data into the public database; Apple will send you the bill when/if your app user exceeds the public database quota allowed per user per app. [yes, so the more users for your app, the more public database quota you get, but you should/need to limit the amount individual users can claim to limit your liability for iCloud costs!]

I may have miss-understood Apple's description of how it works/is going to bill users/apps the last paragraph, open to clarification by all means.

Comment: Thanks for the code, tried that earlier and it wasn't working....identifier... I have a number of issues but the biggest one is having a contractor upload 50MB - 100MB per item with read and write capability, then the consumer would access that from the public DB generating reports for them to download. So there needs to be some way for them only to access that item and not all the others items that were posted by various other contractors. I need some type of login other than the cloud login with passwords set for each item. Would the server-to-server allow me to get the data to my server?

Comment: You could add a login to your code and associate a searchable reference UUID with it in a common DB that the consumer and contractor could look up each others reference UUID and search for records filed by said contractor/consumer. But as I said in my final paragraph you need to be very careful with volumes of data in the public database. I a vague recollection a slightly different set of rules apple for assets [which is what you would need for 50/100mb] but they be linked to your app, not the iCloud account user!

Comment: They are aware of the data limits and charges and want to go ahead with it. Will have to limit photos somehow once we get running. The UUID would be good. The app works so that all data can be stored on phone for later upload(might not have wifi at the time of data collection). The consumer may download the consumer app and request access from the contractor, I can verify the UUID. The consumer may purchase later then I need to grant access to the item with a request, verify they should have access, and then grant access by their UUID? They say they will have an Icloud DB Admin to do this?