# Cloudkit and Security Roles

Tags: security, roles, cloudkit

So I am very interested in using Cloudkit but the documentation on anything over the basic features is horrible. I am looking to establish two basic user types: standard user (someone that can read records only) and an Admin user (can create and modify records). I setup security roles to reflect this and changed the access modifiers on each of the record types to include these roles. However, I cannot find anywhere how to change a user from one role to the other. I have implemented an Admin login of sorts in the app. Once they enter in the appropriate credentials, I want to allow that user to start editing records.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think it's still not possible to assign a security role to a user using code. Then this answer is still valid: [How do I access security role in cloudkit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25570212/how-do-i-access-security-role-in-cloudkit)